# Unwanted borders appearing and div shifting positions in IE10 when div is clicked on

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-10

I tried searching for answers online, couldn't find anything.

1. When I click on a div in IE10, a thin red border appears. The intention is for nothing to happen when the divs are clicked on. I've tried "border:none" and "outline:none" on a few divs to test it out and that solution doesn't work.
2. Also, when some divs are clicked on, it shifts all adjacent divs over to the right.

Any ideas on what could be causing this and how to resolve them?

More info:

- Neither of these issues are happening in Mozilla or Firefox.
- Using Bootstrap.css for input field stylings but not for individual div
  stylings.
- I can include my code but the problem is occurring on
  almost all other divs throughout my files

UPDATE:

1. I started to notice a pattern (still in process of testing all occurrences) that the red border appears when the div contains label tag and input type in it.
2. Below is the HTML/CSS/JS code.

HTML:

```
<div id="setup-container">

    <div class="ppp-intro font-size-130">
        <h1 class="center" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">TEXT</h1>
        <h4 style="margin-bottom: 40px;">TEXT</h4>
    </div>

    <form action="/setup" method="post" class="form">

        <div id="signup">
            <?php foreach ( $results['setup'] as $setup ) { ?>
                <div class="setup-wrapper">
                    <div class="settings-label"><input type="checkbox" name="setup[]" id="<?php echo strtolower( $setup->name ) ?>" class="setup" value="<?php echo $setup->id ?>" style="visibility: hidden" /></div>
                    <label for="<?php echo strtolower( $setup->name ) ?>" class="<?php echo strtolower( $setup->name ) ?>"><?php echo $setup->name ?></label>
                    <div class="setup-label"><?php echo $setup->name ?></div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="messageContainer"></div>
        <div class="buttons"><input type="submit" name="setupSelect" value="Select" /></div>

    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/checkmate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/checkmateCall.js"></script>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.setup-wrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 154px;
    margin: 0 18px 22px 18px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;}

.setup-label {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 110%;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 0 0 14px;}

.settings-label {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;}

#signup {overflow: hidden}
#signup label {float: left;}

#setup-container {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 980px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 10px;}
```

Thank you

Comment: We need to see some code. IE10 doesn't automatically put red borders on things, so your CSS or JS must contain something causing that to happen.

Comment: Hi, Jacob. I've updated the post with our code. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks. That helps, but I don't see your CSS mentioning any red borders, so it may be in your bootstrap.css file or in one of those checkmate JS files. I'd recommend you look for which file is responsible for those borders.